# Moto G 2nd Gen Touch Screen Stopped working

Tags: motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G 2nd Gen (2014) and the screen is working but will not respond to being touched. I dropped it today, only so that it fell about an inch, and it does have a silicon case, and nothing broke, but the touch screen has stopped responding. After this, the touch screen has worked for two brief instances, and then stopped working. 
EDIT: This seems to be when I squeeze the area around the connector to the screen, (the position according to [this guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Motorola+Moto+G+2nd+gen.+2014+LCD+screen+Replacement/36180)).

I have already tried rebooting it by holding down the power button for 10 seconds, and factory resetted it by using the volume keys in the Android Boot Loader. Can I fix this myself or do I need to send it back to Motorola?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to send it back to Motorola or a service center, because while you might try and fix your phone and get some results , there is also a significant chance of damaging your phone further.

Since the problem seems to be the screen the tech professionals might need to replace it or fix the problem in a similar manner.
You can also try to purchase the screen yourself and try to replace it , but thats really not advisable unless you're sure of what you're doing and you have diagnosed the problem correctly.

I strongly suggest you send it to a Motorola service center.
The screen can be purchased at:

(DO NOT PURCHASE THIS UNLESS YOU WANT TO REPLACE IT YOURSELF)
http://www.dhgate.com/product/1-pcs-free-hk-post-shipping-lcd-display-for/209710530.html#s1-1-1